# Print accuracy for YOLOv5 model?

Tags: opencv, deep-learning, pytorch, yolov5

I want to print the accuracy of my trained model. I do understand when I use the model through the camera it shows me the accuracy on the box only, but I want to see the accuracy of my whole model rather than a single instance of my image.

```py
cap  = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# loop through labels
for label in labels:
    print('Collecting images for {}'.format(label)) #so that we can see when transitioning through images
    time.sleep(5)  #sleep or wait for 5 seconds when transitioning between image for other class
    
    # Loop through image range
    for img_num in range(number_imgs):
        print('Collecting images for {}, image number {}'.format(label, img_num))
        
        # webcam feed
        ret, frame = cap.read()   # read the feed from the web cam and store it in given vars
        
        # Naming image path
        imgname = os.path.join(IMAGES_PATH, label+'.'+str(uuid.uuid1())+'.jpg')
        
        #Writes out image to file
        cv2.imwrite(imgname,frame)
        
        # Render to screen
        cv2.imshow('Image Collection', frame)
        
        # 2 sec delay between diff captures
        time.sleep(2)
        
        if cv2.waitKey(10) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

```
!cd yolov5 && python train.py --img 320 --batch 16 --epochs 500 --data dataset.yml --weights yolov5s.pt
```

```py
model = torch.hub.load('ultralytics/yolov5', 'custom', path='yolov5/runs/train/exp/weights/last.pt', force_reload=True)
while cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    # Make detections 
    results = model(frame)
    
    cv2.imshow('YOLO', np.squeeze(results.render()))
    
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
        
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.waitKey(1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yolov5 model dont have a particular feature like accuracy. Instead you can use the `confidence` of every object that is being detected in the frame.

Which you can get from passing `--save-conf` in command line along with

`python3 detect.py --weights '' --source '' --save-conf`